# Why is a semaphore called a semaphore?

Tags: semaphore

It doesn't seem to me that a railway semaphore describes a semaphore better than any other generic signalling object, like a flag or a stoplight. Even something like a keyring (people take keys off the ring to access locked resources, then return them when they're finished) is more descriptive. So why is a semaphore called a semaphore?

Comment: The real question is why the two operations on a semaphore are called P and V.

Comment: I searched for semaphore etymology and the only links I found were for why the operations are called P and V. Nobody explained why they were called semaphores!

Comment: What is the origin of the word etymology? The real question is: why is it called a 'flashlight'? ('torch' is right out.) Due to ancient battery technology  where the voltage would fall very fast as current was drawn, you had to blip the flashlight on for just a moment at a time. The good old days, eh?

Comment: IIRC P and V are initials the first letters of the words for "set" and "get" in Dutch, or something like that.

Comment: Original semaphore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_line

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's the metaphor that the creator of the idea proposed.

The idea was proposed by Dutch computer scientist [Edsger Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) in the early 1960s.

I don't speak Dutch, but looking at [the paper he wrote](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd00xx/EWD35.PDF) on the subject, it looks like he talks about ***seinpaal*** which translates in English to *"signal post"* or [semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore).

He describes the concept as:

> Go to sleep, we'll wake you up again when you need to continue.

This sounds to me like a metaphor for a train driver approaching a semaphore and stopping until being allowed to resume.

[image: semaphore and train]

He says in the paper:

> From now on I will call the logical variable that prohibits the machine from continuing on as ***seinpaal*** (or **semaphore**)

If created by an English-speaker, they might have chosen something else. But for a Dutch-speaker in the 1960s, this analogy must have made the most sense to describe what the idea was.

Comment: I was going to write an answer about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_(railway_signalling), but from your description of "go to sleep, we'll wake you when you need to continue", it sounds more like a railway signal.

Comment: @Gaurav yeah, that Token thing is either brilliant or raving mad. I was stunned when I saw a TV show explaining it. But, we all carry phones nowadays that allow us to proceed with things, so...